# Python: how to make indices of second array match indices of first array when first array gets sorted?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have two Numpy arrays: `a: [2,5,3,7,9,1]` and `b: [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. I want to sort a, and have the elements of `b` shift in the same way that the indices of `a` do. In this case, `a` would become `[1,2,3,5,7,9]` and `b` would become `[6,1,3,2,4,5]`. I know how to use `np.sort` to sort `a`, but how would I re-arrange `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NumPy's `argsort`:

```
>>> b[a.argsort()]
array([6, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
```

An alternative without NumPy:

```
>>> a, b = zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9)
>>> b
(6, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5)
```

Comment: As an aside, I think the pure Python solution may result in an unstable sort of `a`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Hmm, right. For `a` itself it probably doesn't matter (if it's just numbers), but it affects the order of `b`. I could do `a, _, b = zip(*sorted(zip(a, range(len(a)), b)))` or so, but that's less pretty...

Comment: Maybe `a, b = zip(*sorted(zip(a, b), key=itemgetter(0)))`? Just dropping the comparison on the second element.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Looks good. Or a trick one: `sorted(b, key=partial(next, iter(a)))` :-)